# How can I read from keyboard a string of only 4 alphanumeric characters, not one less, not one more

Tags: c, string, string-length

I need to understand how to read from keyboard a string of a precise number of characters.

This function is called from the `main`.

```
void get_string(char *prompt,
            char *input,
            int length)
{
    printf("%s", prompt);

    if (!fgets(input, length, stdin))
    {
        printf("\nErrore: Inserisci correttamente la stringa.\n");
        get_string(prompt, input, length);
    }
    return;
}
```

The string, after being acquired, will be copied into `input [length]`.

Comment: Please show us the body of the function, even though it is not complete and not working, so that we understand what you have already tried and where you might have gotten stuck.

Comment: Use `fgetc` in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>use `scanf("%4s")`. The 4 before the `s` stops saving the input after 4th char.</strike>

```
char buf[4];
scanf("%4s", buf);
printf("%s\n", buf);

input:  123abc
output: 123a
```

This solution is wrong ,as it would read not only alphanumeric.

My 2nd attempt was changing the `scanf` to this `scanf("%4[a-zA-Z0-9]s", buf);` but that would stop upon a non-alphanumeric, so still no good.

A correct way would be this (loop, scan 1 char, check if alphanumeric):

```
char buf[32] = "";
for(unsigned idx = 0; idx < 4; )
{
    int c = getchar();
    if(isalnum(c))
    {
        buf[idx] = c;
        idx++;
    }

}
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Comment: You should zero-terminate your `buf` array before printing it. With `char buf[32] = ""` you ask the compiler to  create code to copy a zero to the first byte of your array.

Comment: @jens: not so. The initializer clears the entire array.

Answer (score -1):

As I read from another answer, you could perform this through a scanf function like this:

```
scanf("%3s", string);
```

Where 3 is the maximum number of characters able to be read. Remember that if you want to read n characters, your array has to be n+1 long because of the null terminator '\0'

Hope this helps,

Comment: I deleted that because that wasn't reading only alphanumeric (which is what the OP wants). Try input "----"

Comment: OP wants four characters, which means they will have to provide a five-byte buffer si they can use `%4s` (or `%4[`).